# Trying to find daily difference for field in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have this.

```
head(df2)
           Close  Group
2007-01-03 17.625 S    
2007-01-04 17.645 B    
2007-01-05 17.570 B    
2007-01-08 17.505 B    
2007-01-09 17.430 B    
2007-01-10 17.375 S
```

I am trying to find the daily change of 'Close'.

I tried this:  `dailychange <- diff(df2$Close)`

That didn't work because 'non-numeric argument to binary operator'.  This is a time series, but I don't think that matters at all.

```
str(df2)
‘zoo’ series from 2007-01-03 to 2018-07-27
  Data: chr [1:2913, 1:2] "17.625" "17.645" "17.570" "17.505" "17.430" "17.375" "17.905" "17.950" "18.110" "18.145" ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:2913] "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:2] "Close" "Group"
  Index:  Date[1:2913], format: "2007-01-03" "2007-01-04" "2007-01-05" "2007-01-08" "2007-01-09" "2007-01-10" "2007-01-11" "2007-01-12" ...
```

Comment: `diff(df2$Close)` works well for me. Check the class if `df$Close` in your data

Comment: Why dont you share output of `str(df2)`?

Comment: If you want to represent this as a time series use +1 and -1 instead of B and S so that it remains numeric.  Alternately create a separate time series for B and S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of `ts`:

> a vector or matrix of the observed time-series values. A data frame
>   will be coerced to a numeric matrix via data.matrix

But, a timeseries with a character column will transform all columns into character. The same behaviour can be seen in a matrix with a character value.

Either keep your data in as a data.frame, or use `as.numeric` inside your diff statement.

```
dailychange <- diff(as.numeric(df2$Close))
dailychange
[1]  0.020 -0.075 -0.065 -0.075 -0.055
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message arises because some data is not numerical. Only numerical data can be used in diff(). Check your data in the close column to check if the data is numerical.